# Call jQuery From Google SpreadSheet Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I use jQuery in a script attached to a Google Spreadsheet?  The [Google Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) page seems to make it simple but apparently I misunderstand the execution environment for Libraries, calling `google.load()` in the script fails.

So what is the right way to do this?  I can imagine ideas like calls on `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` but that doesn't seem like the right way.

(I know I get confused with the various Google App environments, so to be clear: I'm talking about a script saved in the 'script editor' under Tools on the menu for a Google Docs Spreadsheet.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can use external scripts in Google Apps Script.

Comment: You definitely can, I've seen the pattern << eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(...url...).getContentText()) >> used to pull in third party scripts.

Comment: Let me rephrase - I don't think you're *supposed to* -- which your pattern clearly shows. :-P

Comment: it is possible however? I'd also like to use $.(ajax) in a google script linked to a spreadsheet, to scrape a webpage.

Comment: "I'd also like to use $.(ajax) in a google script linked to a spreadsheet, to scrape a webpage. – " I´m searching for the exact same thing. Did you get any where with this?!

Comment: I'm also adding my name to this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to use jQuery from Google Apps Script, but only through the HtmlService, and only in client-side scripts. It's mentioned in the [HtmlService Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices?hl=en#take_advantage_of_jquery) documentation.

Some examples you'll find here on StackOverflow:

- [Browser Pop up in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919638/broswer-pop-up-in-google-apps-script/17929410#17929410)
- [How to make a tab panel using HTML Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581271/google-apps-script-html-service-and-tab-panel/18581972#18581972)
- [jQuery onblur with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205397/jquery-onblur-with-google-apps-script)
- [Populate jQuery autocomplete list using value array from Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216)
- [Use HtmlService, CSS & jQuery to overlay images in Google Apps Script WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914122/use-htmlservice-css-jquery-to-overlay-images-in-google-apps-script-webapp/17930568#17930568)
- [How do I run Server-side functions using HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958298/how-do-i-run-server-side-functions-using-htmlservice/17961595#17961595)
- [Using DataTables plug-in in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793873/using-datatables-plug-in-in-jquery)