# Use CSS & jQuery to overlay images in Google Apps Script HtmlService WebApp

Tags: jquery, css, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to use [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/) to display the progress my company has made towards a goal via a "horse race" scenario. (The idea is to have an image of a horse move from left to right across another image of a horse track. The value of our goal is a number between **`0`** and **`60`** and is stored in a Google spreadsheet.)

I have figured out how to print the value on the screen and how to use JavaScript ([jQuery](https://jquery.com)) to update the `CSS` to move the horse. However, I haven't been able to connect the two together. Here's what I've been able to come up with:

**My `Code.gs` file**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();    
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .getContent();
}

function getHeadCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Horse race headcount");
  var hC = sheet.getRange(24, 2);
  var headCount = hC.getValue();

  return headCount
}
```

**My `Page.html` file**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>    
<!-- the above code serves the same purpose as an href for a style sheet --> 

    <div id='page' width="100%">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/j1hUEvx.jpg" width="96%" />
            <div><p>Consultant Starts: <?!= getHeadCount(); ?> </p></div>
            <!-- the < ? != tag is for inserting the value of the function into the template -->                    

            <div id="mustang">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CFtqjuy.png" />
            </div>
                <div id='scale'>
                    <div class='block' id='one'><span>start</span></div>
                    <div class='block' id='two'><span>10</span></div>
                    <div class='block' id='three'><span>20</span></div>
                    <div class='block' id='four'><span>30</span></div>
                    <div class='block' id='five'><span>40</span></div>
                    <div class='block' id='six'><span>50</span></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

**My `css.html` file:**

```
<style>   
    #page {
        background-color: f0f0f0;
        padding: 5px;          
    } 

    #wrapper { 
        margin: 0 auto;          
    }

   #mustang {
       position: relative;
       top: -347px;
       left: <?!= horseRace(); ?> <!-- 38% for 31 headCount -->                          
   }

    #scale {
       display: inline;
       text-align: center;
       width: 96%;
    }

    .block {
          float: left;
          position: relative; 
          width: 16%; 
          height: 30px;
          top: -400px;    
     }

     div p {
         width:100px;
         height: 50px;
         background-color: #f0f0f0; 
         position: relative;
         top: -300px;        
     }     

     #one {
          background-color: #1F78B4;
     }

     #two {
          background-color: #33A02C; 
     }

     #three {
          background-color: #E31A1C;
     }

     #four {
          background-color: #FF7F00;
     }

     #five {
          background-color: #6A3D9A;
     }

     #six {         
          background-color: #18258B;
     } 
</style>
```

I also have a `JavaScript.html` file, although I haven't had any luck using it to update the `CSS` from calling `getHeadCount();`.

Any suggestions or ideas? I'm sure there is a way to do this - I'm just having problems as I'm new to programming in general. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Also, you can't use a HTML comment in a style sheet can you? HTML <!-- your comment here
CSS /* your comment here */ Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can manipulate elements of style. In this case, you want to change `$(#mustang).left`. Since your `include()` function simply treats all files as an Html file (not a template), it's not doing any template expansion anyway, so clean up the css:

```
 #mustang {
     position: relative;
     top: -347px;
     left: 0%    
 }
```

Now, in your `JavaScript.html`, you need a function that will run when the page is loaded, which will collect the current `headCount` and use it to set the style value that positions your horse.

```
<script>

// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(positionHorse)
      .getHeadCount();
});

function positionHorse(headCount) {
  var position = 100 * headCount / 60;
  $('#mustang').css('left', (position)+'%');
}

</script>
```

**Note:** If you had instead treated your css as a template, and called `evaluate()` on it, that might have done the trick for you.

Your `doGet()` shouldn't work as posted... it doesn't return the htmlOutput. Here's what I used for testing:

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService
                 .createTemplateFromFile('Page');

  var htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
                   .setTitle('Horse Race');

  return htmlOutput;
}
```

[image: Result]