# How do I move an html dialog window? (Google spreadsheet apps script dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

In apps scripts, the html dialog pops up square in the middle of the window. I want to move that out of the way because the user's interaction with the dialog will show up in the spreadsheet behind the dialog. Seems like a good thing to allow the user to see what is happening there.

I can change the height and size of the dialog window, but there is no method to move the window. Spreadsheets can't have app script generated sidebars and I tried to do it in javascript: window.moveTo(0,0) : no dice.

Another way would be to reduce it to something small and then popup a jquery window over it, which could be moved: 
[Browser Pop up in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919638/browser-pop-up-in-google-apps-script/17929410#17929410)

Any best practices for this problem? Otherwise, I jquery seems to offer the best solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I find that a webApp is the best way to go. It gives complete control of the window and it can be launched through the menu of the calling spreadsheet. (I'm still working on the application, but a webapp seems to be the best way to go, especially since there is jquery for fancy interaction.)