# How to make a tab panel using HTML Service

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-caja

How I can integrate a tabs panel to display in each tab a different HTML content and allow also the navigation of those panels, in [Google Apps Script HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)?

I tried to implement this simple code but it doesn't work, due to caja sanitization, it seems.

```
<pre><ul id="tabs">
     <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <a name="tab1" id="tab1"></a>
        <h2>Tab 1</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...</p>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <a name="tab2" id="tab2"></a>
        <h2>Tab 2</h2>

        <p>Convallis elit tortor ut ante libero Aenean Maecenas ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <a name="tab3" id="tab3"></a>
        <h2>Tab 3</h2>

        <p>Urna justo quam nunc urna sem facilisis nibh Curabitur tellus quis...</p>
    </div>
</div></pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special attention is paid to ensure [HtmlService compatibility with jQueryUi](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-caja#jquery_and_jquery_ui), and this is a good opportunity to use it. The [jQueryUi Tabs example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) will work with very little modification.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('tabs')
                       .setTitle('jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality')
                       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

  return app;
}
```

#### tabs.html

```
<!-- head -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

<!-- body -->

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad, i tried your code but it seems that when i try to change tabs, the html code still remain the html code of the first tab. Have you tried? Urls seems are modified from caja like this... https://script.google.com/a/macros/mydomain.com/s/xxxxx/exec#tabs-3-caja-guest-0___  appending -caja-guest-0___ at the end...

Comment: Of course I tried it - answer has been updated with additional screenshots, showing tab contents change with tab selection. However, I used the `/dev` link, and there, at least, it works fine. I didn't anticipate any different for the published URL, yet as you say, it doesn't work there. Will have to dig some more. (Does yours work on the `/dev` link?)

Comment: I found the error..i tried in Chrome and it works. It's in firefox that doesn't work...firefox version 23.0.1....can you confirm this? Thanks

Comment: I was just about to add that comment myself. Works in IE 10 as well, but not firefox. I've found numerous tips to address the FF problem, but haven't stumbled on a solution yet. I've added a note to the answer, and also updated the code to use Google's hosted libraries.

Comment: Problem was with the 1.10.3 themes. Code updated, works on Firefox now.

Comment: The screenshot and result that we get does not match now, is there any change required due to any update?