# is it possible to use Checkboxes in a listbox using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using GAS I would like to use checkboxes in a listbox (and check several of them). Is this possible ?

I would like to avoid alternatives like using a flextable or maybe even a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UiApp Service does not support combining the two elements. A `ListBox` does support multiple selections (<kbd>shift</kbd>-click, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click), and you can position multiple `CheckBox` items into a `VerticalPanel` to provide a logical grouping for your users.

If you instead use the `HtmlService` for your user interface, you will have many more options, including widgets like [Eric Hynd's jQueryUI Multi-Select widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget):

[image: screenshot]

Here is how that same widget looks, in a Google Document sidebar (code follows, although without any input handling):

[image: screenshot]

#### Code.gs

```
/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
 *     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
 *     AuthMode.NONE.)
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar')
      .setTitle('MultiSelect').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

#### Sidebar.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
<!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

<style>
.ui-multiselect {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-multiselect { padding:2px 0 2px 4px; text-align:left }
.ui-multiselect span.ui-icon { float:right }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes input { position:absolute !important; top: auto !important; left:-9999px; }
.ui-multiselect-single .ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { padding:5px !important }

.ui-multiselect-header { margin-bottom:3px; padding:3px 0 3px 4px }
.ui-multiselect-header ul { font-size:0.9em }
.ui-multiselect-header ul li { float:left; padding:0 10px 0 0 }
.ui-multiselect-header a { text-decoration:none }
.ui-multiselect-header a:hover { text-decoration:underline }
.ui-multiselect-header span.ui-icon { float:left }
.ui-multiselect-header li.ui-multiselect-close { float:right; text-align:right; padding-right:0 }

.ui-multiselect-menu { display:none; padding:3px; position:absolute; z-index:10000; text-align: left }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes { position:relative /* fixes bug in IE6/7 */; overflow-y:scroll }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label { cursor:default; display:block; border:1px solid transparent; padding:3px 1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes label input { position:relative; top:1px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li { clear:both; font-size:0.9em; padding-right:3px }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label { text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1px solid }
.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li.ui-multiselect-optgroup-label a { display:block; padding:3px; margin:1px 0; text-decoration:none }

</style>

<div class="sidebar branding-below">
  <form>
    <div class="block" id="button-bar">
      <button class="blue" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="multi-select">
      <select id="ms-example" name="ms-example" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="8">Option 8</option>
        <option value="9">Option 9</option>
        <option value="10">Option 10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="sidebar bottom">
  <img alt="Add-on logo" class="logo" height="27"
      id="logo"
      src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/adad1d8ad010a76a83574b1fff4caa46?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <span class="gray branding-text">by Mogsdad, D.Bingham</span>
</div>

<!--- Load libraries & css as required for jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget
<---- http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget
<---- NOTE: jquery.multiselect.css would not pass caja when loaded, so has
<---- been replicated in <style> tags at top of this file. -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/master/src/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<!---<link rel="http://erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/jquery.multiselect.css" /> -->

<script>
/**
 * On document load, assign click handlers to button(s), add
 * elements that should start hidden (avoids "flashing"), and
 * start polling for document selections.
 */
$("#ms-example").multiselect({
   selectedText: "# of # selected"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it causes a problem to me. a) Can I combine UiApp with HtmlService (if so  : how?) b) How to migrate from UiApp to HtmlService (detailed info somewhere?) ?

Comment: They can't be combined, but a project could use both at separate times. IMO the wide variety of ways you can implement a UiApp ui would make a migration guide impossible to follow. Personally, I've viewed my existing UiApp forms and dialogs as specifications for HtmlApp versions, and reimplemented them. You will find many (sometimes too many) examples of html forms with accompanying javascript / jQuery / CSS to create any UI you wish. (This answer was a good example - took just 15 minutes, +1 hr to sort out the css/caja problem. See [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581972/1677912).)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean in uiService. Not possible.
Possible in htmlService.