# google apps script jQRangeSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I am creating my own form with Google apps script.
I could also set values ​​for google spread sheet and introduce bootstrap.
But I can't use jQRangeSlider.http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/

I want to use this file 'jQRangeSlider-min.js'.

Please tell me how to use jQRangeSlider-min.js for google apps script.

Comment: You can only use HTMLService to call the jquery file as stated in this [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices?hl=en#take_advantage_of_jquery). You can also check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407484/5995040) to see some examples. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Apps Script (GAS) you can use the **HTML Service** to create and serve html able to interact with server-side functions, so if you're trying to create a webpage in GAS I'm going to assume that you already know that.

If you want to use the jQRangeSlider library inside of your html document, you can do it by pointing to the library uploaded on a cdn (ie https://cdnjs.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQRangeSlider/5.7.2/jQEditRangeSlider.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can just copy the content of the min library into an html document between `<script>` tags

```html
<script>
  // ALL THE JAVASCRIPT LIBRARY CONTENT GOES HERE
</script>
```

And then include the content in your main html document, but for doing so you have to create a method in your GAS file (.gs) to import the file content, so your .gs will end up looking like this

```html
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}
```

And your main html could resemble this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('jQuery.min.js'); ?>
    <?!= include('jQEditRangeSlider.min.js'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

These are some links to the documentation about this subject.

[Html Service Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)

[Html Service Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)

[Html Service: Create and Serve Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)